# How to get sprites react to touches in cocos2d android?

Tags: android, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, touch, cocos2d-android

i have 1 gun when tap on any point on the screen bullets fires out, but according to my requirement there are 3 guns(sprites) when touched on any of the sprites bullets must fire up, when googled i came to know that this can be done by using targetedTouchDelegate or to loop all the spirites and set flag for each touched sprite, i have seen the code for this in iphone, but could not find for android, please can anybody tell how to use do this in android? or any links or books for cocos2d-android would be useful not only for me to others also. Thanks,

Comment: have you got the answer for this ?

Comment: nope :( @user26534 u have any idea on it?

Answer (score 0):

Well what I would do in such a case would be get the rect for my sprite using this

```
CGRect projectileRect = CGRect
                .make(sprite.getPosition().x
                        - (sprite.getContentSize().width / 2.0f),
                        sprite.getPosition().y
                                - (sprite.getContentSize().height / 2.0f),
                        sprite.getContentSize().width,
                        sprite.getContentSize().height);
```

and I will detect if the clicked point is in the rectangle of that particular sprite 
you can override onccTouchBegan to get the clicked point and then look for the collision

```
@Override
public boolean ccTouchesBegan(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CGPoint touchLocation=CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY());
    CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(
            event.getX(),
            event.getY(),
            5,
            5);

        if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect))
                  1st sprite is clicked 

    return super.ccTouchesBegan(event);

}
```

This is my work around.

Comment: thanks for your reply, how to tell 1st sprite is clicked? @Aashish Bhatnagar

Comment: Just a example you can make different rects for different sprites since I have only one its first