# How to add listener to a sprite in cocos2d in android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

i am working on cocos2d,and i am in the need of adding a listener to a sprite.my code is here

```
public class GameOverScreen extends CCLayer implements KeyHandler {

public static CCScene scene(Difficulty difficulty, long totalscore) {

    CCScene result = CCScene.node();

    CCSprite redeem = CCSprite.sprite("redeem.png");// listener to this sprite
    CGSize s = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize();
    redeem.setScale(Block.SCALE*Main.SCALE);
    redeem.setPosition(-1, -1);

    redeem.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(-0.7f, -1));

    result.addChild(new GameOverScreen(NewHighscore, totalscore));
    result.addChild(redeem);

    return result;


}
```

Comment: i dint get, can u elaborate? @user1427756

Comment: @DD. i am in the need to add a touch listener on a sprite...similar type of query is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648196/how-to-get-sprites-react-to-touches-in-cocos2d-android . But this was not working in my case

Comment: what u want on the touch of redeem ?

Comment: CCMenuItemImage class , you can use for the touch on the CCsprite redeem ...

Comment: I want to open Revmob adlink ,,,, i.e random app in google play

Comment: I have added an answer . try this but I'm sure about revmob adlink work in it cz I doesn't use this

Comment: have you sucessfully  done with the Revmob Adlink  ?

Comment: that was already been done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public boolean ccTouchesBegan(MotionEvent event) {
 location = CCDirector.sharedDirector().convertToGL(CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY()));

     if(CGRect.containsPoint((redeem.getBoundingBox()), location)){
      //Action
     }  
 return true;
}
```

Short and simple trick to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

you can do this thing :

```
CCMenuItemImage item1 = CCMenuItemImage.item("redeem.png","redeem.png", this,"function_name");

CCMenu menu = CCMenu.menu(item1);
     menu.setPosition(CGPoint.make(0, 0));
     item1.setPosition(CGPoint.make(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2));
```

function_name is used when you click on the redeem image(Sprite)

```
public void function_name(Object sender) 
{
// what you want to perform on the click like : enter the CCScene etc.  
}
```

Comment: For a single button,,, implementing CCMenu,, is not a good option ,,, i think..... Anyways Thankyou for the reply

Answer (score 0):

i have found the solution and the code is this:

```
public static CCScene scene(Difficulty difficulty, long totalscore) {
    boolean NewHighscore = Settings.Current().addToHighscore(difficulty, totalscore);

    CCScene result = CCScene.node();

    CCSprite redeem = CCSprite.sprite("redeem.png");
    s = CCDirector.sharedDirector().winSize();
    redeem.setScale(Block.SCALE*Main.SCALE);
    redeem.setPosition(s.width/2, s.height/4);




    result.addChild(new GameOverScreen(NewHighscore, totalscore));
    result.addChild(redeem);


    projectileRect = CGRect
            .make(redeem.getPosition().x
                    - (redeem.getContentSize().width / 2.0f),
                    redeem.getPosition().y
                            - (redeem.getContentSize().height / 2.0f),
                            redeem.getContentSize().width,
                            redeem.getContentSize().height);



    return result;

}

@Override
public  boolean ccTouchesBegan(MotionEvent event) {


    CGPoint touchLocation=CGPoint.ccp(event.getX(), event.getY());
    CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(
            event.getX(),
            s.height-event.getY(),
            5,
            5);




        if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect))
        {
            System.out.println("here inside intersection");
            // RevMob functionality
        }



    return super.ccTouchesBegan(event);


}
```

Comment: you can use the above code and both are equally same but you can reduce the code weight